# Is there a SIM card that works in Spain, France, and Italy?

Tags: europe, france, cellphones, spain

I am traveling to Europe later this month and I have an iPhone 5. What companies offer prepaid SIM cards that work in Spain, France, and Italy, if there are any?

*the iPhone 5 is CDMA and GSM compatible.*

Comment: Any SIM card with roaming allowed will work in all of those 3 countries as long as your phone is capable of working with GSM networks in Europe.  If not can you clarify your question?

Comment: Polling for recommendations is generally not allowed here as you'll get conflicting answers and ideas (see [help]).  When you edit your question, please edit that part as well.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I will actually just leave this closed because I can't think of a good way to make this more specific and/or not make this a poll for recommendations.

Comment: @Hewins pity that you leave it closed, I was about to give you an extensive answer

Comment: I reworded my question. Can someone take it off of hold?

Comment: @andra thanks for your comment. I reworded my question. Karlson, Mark Mayo, drat, Dirty-flow, VMAtm, is this better?

Answer (score 2):

You'll be hard pressed to find a sim card that won't work in all three countries if it works in one.

But, as has already been pointed out, the cost of calling and receiving calls will be significant. At least until roaming charges will be limited from late next year onward (if my memory serves me well).

In the mean time, you could consider a 'universal' sim card, like this one:

https://www.simcardglobal.com/Universal-SIM-Card/A/28/

Comment: Roaming charges are banned from 15 December 2015: http://www.europarl.europa.eu/news/en/news-room/content/20140331IPR41232/html/Ensure-open-access-for-internet-service-suppliers-and-ban-roaming-fees-say-MEPs

Answer (score 1):

I think all the major carriers will work but can cost you a huge pile of money.

T-mobile has a free (no additional cost) data/text plan with their Simple Choice plan.
http://www.t-mobile.com/optional-services/roaming.html